# É bem tri. Está tri. O que é tri?

Tags: português-brasileiro, significado, vocabulário

A palavra **tri** é comumente usada no sul do Brasil em diversas situações. Mas o que ela quer dizer?

The word **tri** is commonly used in southern Brazil in various situations. But what does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A palavra *tri* pode ter principalmente dois significados.

- Legal
- Muito

Tudo vai depender de como ela é empregada.

**Exemplos:**

- Esse carro é muito *tri*. - Legal.
- A festa tava *tri* legal. - Muito
- Que *tri* o teu cabelo! - Legal
- O passeio foi *tri* pra caramba - Legal

Comment: Mas bah, que tri essa pergunta tchê!

Comment: @LucasMotta hahah agora explica pros guri de apartamento o que é bah e tchê.

Comment: What? Estou chocado. De onde vem a palavra?

Comment: @JorgeB. até onde tenho conhecimento só é utilizado no sul do Brasil